# How to retrieve a request scoped variable using JSTL on Struts 1

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl, struts-1

I'm refactoring some legacy code that uses Struts 1 (No flames please), and I am having a difficult time retrieving a parameter I set in my Action class. Here is the code that I'm using in my jsp:

I set the variable `submissionFailure` in the Action Class, but when I try

`<c:out value="${requestScope[cardHolderZipCode]}" />`

or

`<c:out value="${requestScope.property[submissionFailure]}" />`

However nothing is ever output.

I put the following code in my JSP, and I can see the value in the requestScope Map:

`<b><i>Request Scope</i></b><br/>
<c:forEach items="${requestScope}"  varStatus="status" var="parameter">
    <c:out value="${parameter}"/><br/><br/>

</c:forEach>`

But I still can't get the variable out. Can anyone help me or am I just having an I-D-10-T moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an I-D-10-T moment on my part. I was trying too hard. Here is the code I ended up using:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${submissionFailure}">
         <%-- Do something --%>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
         <%-- Do something else --%>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your Action class is not a JavaBean (i.e. no getter on the submissionFailure field). [From the Struts1 reference](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/faqs/newbie.html#jsp):

> First, your ActionForm bean must have
>   a zero-arguments constructor. This is
>   required because the framework must be
>   able to dynamically create new
>   instances of your form bean class,
>   while knowing only the class name.
>   This is not an onerous restriction,
>   however, because the framework will
>   also populate your form bean's
>   properties (from the request
>   parameters) for you.
>
> Second, the fields of your form bean
>   are made available to the framework by
>   supplying public getter and setter
>   methods that follow the naming design
>   patterns described in the JavaBeans
>   Specification. For most users, that
>   means using the following idiom for
>   each of your form bean's properties:

```
private {type} fieldName;

public {type} getFieldName() {
  return (this.fieldName);
}
public void setFieldName({type} fieldName) {
  this.fieldName = fieldName;
}
```

If this doesn't help, then you should consider posting the relevant parts of your Action class into your question to enable better debugging.